# In GWT how do I handle the tab click event?

Tags: gwt, gwt-tablayoutpanel

I have a tab layout panel in my ui.xml :

```
<g:TabLayoutPanel ui:field="tabPanel" barHeight='30'>
  <g:tab>
    <g:header size='7'>tab1</g:header>
    <g:SimplePanel ui:field="tab1" height="100%"/>
  </g:tab>
  <g:tab>
    <g:header size='7'>tab2</g:header>
    <g:SimplePanel ui:field="tab2" height="100%"/>
  </g:tab>
</g:TabLayoutPanel>
```

how do I handle the event generated on clicking Tab2?

Answer (score 6):

Handle the `SelectionEvent<Integer>` or `BeforeSelectionEvent<Integer>` depending on your requirements.

e.g:

```
tabPanel.addSelectionHandler(new SelectionHandler<Integer>() {
  @Override
  public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<Integer> event) {
    if (event.getSelectedItem() == 1) {
      // Code
    }
  }
});
```

or:

```
@UiHandler("tabPanel")
void onTabSelection(SelectionEvent<Integer> event) {
  if (event.getSelectedItem() == 1) {
    // Code
  }
}
```