# Add tab dynamically using a tab item in GWT

Tags: gwt, gwt-tablayoutpanel

I want to create a tabbed page and load different information on each tab click.

I want to be able to add tabs dynamically when clicked the '+' tab.
[image]

So, on clicking '+' a new tab should be added to the same tabLayoutPanel.

Any suggestions on how to do it in GWT.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Add the '+' tab statically (e.g. ui xml).
- Add a selection handler (see [In GWT how do I handle the tab click event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059214/in-gwt-how-do-i-handle-the-tab-click-event?rq=1) for how to do this).
- In this handler: if the last tab is selected, insert a new tab just before it and select it from code.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add to the tabPanel an empty **+** widget, then add a `selectionChangeHandler` on the tabPanel to detect click on the **+** tab, which add your new tab and select it.

So the `+`tab do the job and is never shown:

```
    tabPanel.add(new Label(), "+");

    tabPanel.addSelectionHandler(new SelectionHandler<Integer>() {

        @Override
        public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<Integer> event) {
            if (event.getSelectedItem() == tabPanel.getWidgetCount() - 1) {                 
                Widget w = new Label(); // the widget which contains the new tab
                tabPanel.insert(w, w.toString(),
                        tabPanel.getWidgetCount() - 1);
                tabPanel.selectTab(w);
            }
        }
    });
```